# Ignore unique key while updating some rows (mariaDB)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, mariadb, mariasql

I have the following table (mariaDB):

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | content_type | sort_number | document_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | text         |           1 |           1 |
|  2 | table        |           2 |           1 |
|  3 | text         |           3 |           1 |
|  4 | image        |           4 |           1 |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The combination of `sort_number` and `document_id` is unique.

Now when i want to add a new entry at position 2, I need to increment the `sort_number` of all entries where the `sort_number >= 2` by one step.

To achieve this, i use the following query:

```
update `table_name` set `sort_number` = sort_number +1 where `sort_number` > ? and `document_id` = ?
```

But because of the unique key (`sort_number` and `document_id`) i get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'table_name_sort_number_document_id_unique'
```

I tired to avoid the error with `SET unique_checks=0;` but still get the error...

Is there a (better) way to update the `sort_number` in one query?

Comment: You need to get the max(sort_number) for document_id and then increment the sort_number of that row

Comment: Add `order by sort_number desc` to your update statement.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY also applies to update query, so simply:

```
SET @i:=0;
UPDATE items SET disp_order=@i:=@i+1 ORDER BY item_name;
```

Simply start updating from the last row and traverse backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution provided by Paul Spiegel. My Query looks now like this:

```
update `table_name` set `sort_number` = sort_number +1 where `sort_number` > ? and `document_id` = ? order by `sort_number` desc
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE IGNORE is the answer

```
UPDATE IGNORE `table_name` set `sort_number` = sort_number +1 where `sort_number` > ? and `document_id` = ?
```